# Center column headings in tabular: multicolumn not respected

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I would like to center column headings (and column headings only) in the following table. Why does it work with the first column, but not the second (I thought `\multicolumn` is the correct approach to this problem).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rr}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\alpha$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\alpha=0.99999$} \\
  \midrule
  10     & 69.681   \\
         & 901.741  \\
  1000   & 893.630  \\
         & 82.806   \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the second column *is* centered; could you clarify what you were hoping for?

Comment: I was hoping that the right-aligned entries are moved sufficiently to the left so that the column label looks more centered than right-aligned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a little example of how you can make a small modification to your input in order to get the desired output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rc}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\alpha$} & $\alpha=0.99999$ \\
  \midrule
  10     & \phantom{0}69.681   \\
         & 901.741  \\
  1000   & 893.630  \\
         & \phantom{0}82.806   \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The addition of a `\phantom` leading 0 for numbers less then 100 makes all the numbers the same width, so `c`entering is readily achieved.

Answer (score 4):

It is centered correctly. The problem is the length (width) of numbers in that column that are right aligned. I mean to say `α = 0.99999` is longer than any of the numbers in that column. As a proof, let us put a slightly bigger number.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rr}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\alpha$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\alpha=0.99999$} \\
  \midrule
  10     & 69.681   \\
         & 901.741  \\
  1000   & 893.630  \\
         & 82.80600000000000000000   \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Argh... you are right, I didn't check that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using the [`dcolumn`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn) package you can get the desired alignment automatically:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\newcolumntype{M}{D{.}{.}{3.3}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rM}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\alpha$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\alpha=0.99999$} \\
\midrule
10     & 69.681   \\
       & 901.741  \\
1000   & 893.630  \\
       & 82.806   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using [`siunitx`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/siunitx) column formatting

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
  r
  S[
      table-format = 3.3,
      input-symbols=.,
  ]
  }
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\alpha$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\alpha=0.99999$} \\
    \midrule
    10     & 69.681   \\
           & 901.741  \\
    1000   & 893.630  \\
           & 82.806   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```