# tabular with "centered" and "flushright" entries

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, dcolumn

I need to typeset a tabular with the following requirement:

- the head of a tabular should be center in the column
- the entries should be **flushright and (more or less) center** in the the 
  column

like in the following example

```
|   -head of a column-   |
--------------------------
|           120          |
|         42001          |
```

I can do this by making each entry of the same width (say with \phantom) and then centering the column, but as a tabular are fairly large it's a lot of tedious work.

I'm aware of the existance of dcolumn package (and answer given here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73702/7313), however I don't know how to use it together with `array` package and features it provides (`\newcolumntype` mostly)

Is there any wiser way to do this?

Comment: `dcolumn` is defined via the `array` package `\newcolumntype` feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dcolumn}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering}p{1cm}}
\newcolumntype{E}{D{.}{.}{5.0}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{C E}
xxx & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{head of col}}\\
y y y  & 120\\
z z z z z  & 42001
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: amazing, that's what is needed. how can you set the width of the right column?

Comment: @pml you set it by the values in the D colunm `D{.}{.}{10}{5}` makes it wide enough for 10 digits to the left of a `.` and 5 digits to the right. It doesn't matter if there are any entries like that it is just a space specification really.